# notificationcompat from service

Tags: android, service, notifications

I'm using NotificationCompat from android service here is my code

```
public void giveNotification(){

    task.cancel();

    Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    NotificationCompat.Builder reminderNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MyService.this);
    reminderNotification.setContentTitle("Times up");
    reminderNotification.setContentText("Application is over used");
    reminderNotification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);


    notificationManager.notify(0,reminderNotification.build());
}
```

I've called function `giveNotification()` from a `timerTask`. Code seems to be right but it is throwing an `IllegalArgumentException()`.

What is wrong in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Gingerbread and below you have to set the content intent, otherwise a `IllegalArgumentException` will be thrown.

So the following should resolve your problem:

```
        //Required on Gingerbread and below
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```